# How can i get the list of countries for signup form in mern stack?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, countries

I am building one project based on the MERN stack. I got stuck in a signup form, it has one field of country. So, how could I get the list of countries or guide me any way by which I could achieve this?

Comment: show some code on what have you tried so far?

Comment: I got the list of countries from the Wikipedia page by scraping it. I get the list in JSON format. Thanks @hafizali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd either have to have the countries in your backend on an URI you could ask from the frontend (GET /countries/) and display them.

Or have them directly in the frontend in a `.json` file and `.map()` it to display the options/autocomplete.

Can't help you more without code or more precision though.